# Activity has leaked window that was originally added here in socialAuth

Tags: android, socialauth

I am fairly new to android. I am getting the above error when im trying to create new SocialAuthDialog in socialAuth. I cant figure out how to work around this. any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void startDialogAuth(final Context context, final Provider provider, final String socialProcedure,
                             final int providerID)
{
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                url =
                        socialAuthManager.getAuthenticationUrl(provider.toString(), provider.getCallBackUri())
                                + "&type=user_agent&display=touch";

                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            new SocialAuthDialog(context, url, provider, dialogListener, socialAuthManager,
                                    socialProcedure, providerID).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.d("Social OAuthAdapter", "-- startDialogAuth :" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Social OAuth Adapter", "-- startDialogAuth : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Comment: Its a common error, are you using `ProgressDialog` or any kind of `dialog`?

Comment: please include full error in question

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)